# Error finding matches and creating new lines in a text file using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have this text in a file

```
random text 1.- random text 2. random text 3.- random 22 text 4. random text
```

I want to create a new line before each number followed by a dot. This is my code:

```
for number in {1..4}
do
var=$(sed -n "s/.*\([^0-9]$number\.[^0-9]\).*/\1/p" file)
echo $var
sed -i "s/$var/\n$var/g" file 
done
```

This is the result I get:

```
random text
 1.- random text
 2. random text
 3.- random
 2. text
 4. random text
```

I do not understand why it creates a new line before the number 22 if there is no dot. The expected result would be this:

```
random text
1.- random text
2. random text
3.- random 22 text
4. random text
```

Could someone help me and explain where my mistake is? Thank you very much

Comment: My statement was wrong, I wanted to say "before". Text is corrected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `number=2` you get `var=' 2.'`

This gets fed into the last `sed` command as `/ 2./\n 2./g` where the first `2.` says to match a literal `2` with any other single character (`.`) which is why it ends up matching on `22`.  Then to confuse ya a bit more, the `\n 2.` says to insert the literal `2.` hence the `22` is replaced with `2.`.

Consider:

```
$ echo '22' | sed 's/2./2./'
2.
```

One quick-fix for the current code is to use [parameter substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) to add a backslash to escape the `.` in `$var`:

```
for number in {1..4}
do
    var=$(sed -n "s/.*\([^0-9]$number\.[^0-9]\).*/\1/p" file)
    var="${var/./\\.}"      # replace "." with "\."
    echo $var
    sed -i "s/$var/\n$var/g" file
done

$ cat file
random text
 1.- random text
 2. random text
 3.- random 22 text
 4. random text
```

The leading space is your match of the first `[^0-9]` in the first `sed` command and since it's inside the parens it's considered part of the capture group and thus gets included in the `\1` reference.  Try moving the left paren to the right by one character, eg:

```
for number in {1..4}
do
    # replace this:
    #var=$(sed -n "s/.*\([^0-9]$number\.[^0-9]\).*/\1/p" file)

    # with this:
    var=$(sed -n "s/.*[^0-9]\($number\.[^0-9]\).*/\1/p" file)

    var="${var/./\\.}"
    echo $var
    sed -i "s/[[:space:]]*$var/\n$var/g" file
done
```

**NOTE:** I've added the `[[:space:]]*` to match on any white space before `$var`; the replacement (`\n$var`) will effectively remove said white space from the end of what will now be the *line-before $var*.

The results:

```
$ cat file
random text
1.- random text
2. random text
3.- random 22 text
4. random text
```

Comment: My statement was wrong, I wanted to say "before". Text is corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

I'd write it using a single `sed` command:

```
sed 's/ \([0-9][0-9]*\.\)/\
\1/g' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`  in a single pass

```
$ sed -i.bak 's/[0-9]*\.[^0-9]*/\n&/g' file
random text
1.- random text
2. random text
3.- random 22 text
4. random text
```